# put space between android buttons

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/o_pharmacy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p2"
    android:text="@string/o_pharmacy"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lab"
    android:text="@string/lab"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/i_pharmacy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p1"
    android:text="@string/i_pharmacy"
    android:textSize="26sp" />
```

I tried above code to display 3 buttons in Liner layout. It works but I need to put space between the two buttons.

Comment: what is the orientation of your LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 34):

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

for each button

Answer (score 20):

If the orientation of your LinearLayout is vertical, use

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

otherwise, use

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/o_pharmacy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p2"
    android:text="@string/o_pharmacy"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lab"
    android:text="@string/lab"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/i_pharmacy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p1"
    android:text="@string/i_pharmacy"
    android:textSize="26sp" />
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make space between 3 buttons in an horizontal LinearLayout to use this on the center button:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

If you have vertical LinearLayout, you can use marginTop and marginBottom.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use android:layout_marginTop="10dp" in your XML activity as this gives accurate spacing between that button and the other button or widget.
Repeat this for rest of the buttons.
Happy Programming!

Comment: Is this a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029378/put-space-between-android-buttons/18029400#18029400)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
                android:id="@+id/o_pharmacy"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"

                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p2"
                android:text="@string/o_pharmacy"
                android:textSize="26sp" />

                   <Button
                   android:id="@+id/lab"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                   android:layout_marginTop="10dip"

                   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lab"
                   android:text="@string/lab"
                   android:textSize="26sp" />

                   <Button
                   android:id="@+id/i_pharmacy"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                   android:layout_marginTop="10dip"

                   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p1"
                   android:text="@string/i_pharmacy"
                   android:textSize="26sp" />
```

I am assuming that you are using a **Vertical orientation** for your LinearLayout, otherwise this code won't make sense as your buttons are **Fill_parent for layout_width**. Notice the line that says `android:layout_marginTop="10dip"` which ensures that you leave a reasonable 10 dip space in between your buttons. Ofcourse, you can increase (or decrease) that space in between your buttons. That's your choice.

Hope this answered your question satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try layout_weight. If you need 3 in a row with some space in between. you can do like this

```
<LinearLayout
                  android:id="@+id/buttons"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                  >

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                      android:id="@+id/o_pharmacy"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="64dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                      android:text="@string/o_pharmacy"


                      />

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                      android:id="@+id/lab"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="64dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                      android:padding="5dp"
                      android:text="@string/lab"


                      />

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                      android:id="@+id/i_pharmacy"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="64dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                      android:text="@string/i_pharmacy"


                      />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use

```
 android:textSize="26dp"
```

instead of

```
android:textSize="26sp"
```

to have a better result in all devices of varied sizes!

Comment: Nope. `sp` is required for text sizes